# Using WPFToolKit's DataGridHyperlinkColumn

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I'm using WPFToolkit's Datagrid control.  I can populate the datagrid, but I'm having trouble with the DataGridHyperlinkColumn.  I would like it to visually display the link as the Person's name, but for the link to go to whatever UriLink's value is.

How can I do this?  What am I doing wrong?

Xaml:

```
<dg:DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Person Name" Width="200" 
Binding="{Binding Path=PersonName}" IsReadOnly="True" 
TargetName="{Binding Path=UriLink}"></dg:DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

Alternatively, I would rather put an event handler in instead, and create the page object to navigate to, but I can't seem to pull any data out of the event's two parameters (o and e in this case), where obj1/obj2 are objects/variables of the clicked hyperlink's row.

Alternative Xaml:

```
<dg:DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Person Name" Width="200" 
Binding="{Binding Path=PersonName}" IsReadOnly="True" 
TargetName="{Binding Path=UriLink}">
    <dg:DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="OnHyperlinkClick" />
    </Style>
    </dg:DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
    </dg:DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

VB code (for Alternative Xaml):

```
Private Sub OnHyperlinkClick(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)

        'TODO: Create page to navigate to
        Dim page As New RedirectPage(obj1, obj2)
        Me.NavigationService.Navigate(page)

End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755455/handle-datagridhyperlinkcolumn-click-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast o as a TextBlock, it's DataContext is your row's object.  You can cast it as your object type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Hyperlink.RequestNavigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.requestnavigate.aspx) event would work better? It looks like the `EventArgs` contains the URI that the navigation target is, which should be the URI of the hyperlink control itself.

Answer (score 0):

As AKCODer said, it's in the DataContext.  Using the OnHyperlinkClick event handler, I used the following:

```
DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(e.Source, System.Object), System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink).DataContext, System.Object)
```