# Handle DataGridHyperlinkColumn Click Event

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How to handle click event of DataGridHyperlinkColumn programatically through code(in .xaml.cs file).

Answer (score 17):

If you just want to navigate the browser to the link, it's a simple as writing a handler like this:

```
void EventSetter_OnHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var destination = ((Hyperlink) e.OriginalSource).NavigateUri;
  Process.Start(destination.ToString());
}
```

If you instead want to take some custom action upon navigation, using information in the associated row, then you will need to access the data context of the hyperlink:

```
void EventSetter_OnHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var rowData = ((Hyperlink) e.OriginalSource).DataContext as User;
  navigationService.NavigateToUserRecordForId(rowData.Id);
}
```

If you want to programatically create a hyperlink column, and bind to it's click event, you can do this:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));

style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(Hyperlink.ClickEvent,     (RoutedEventHandler)EventSetter_OnHandler));

var column = new DataGridHyperlinkColumn { Header = "User", Binding = new Binding("ViewUserLink"), ElementStyle = style };

dataGrid1.Columns.Add(column);
```

This [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651416/using-wpftoolkits-datagridhyperlinkcolumn) also has good info on the WPF toolkit's Data GridHyperlinkColumn, well worth checking out.

Comment: In .NET 6, `Process.Start("https://someurl")` results in exception like: `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to start process 'https://google.com/' with working directory 'D:\Projects\(...)\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`. This code works better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835891/process-starturl-fails/61035650#61035650

Answer (score 13):

use this:

```
<dg:DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
<EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="OnHyperlinkClick" />
</Style>
</dg:DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
</dg:DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```