# "Hyperlink.Click" event not being fired for DataGridHyperlinkColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF form with a `DataGrid` containing multiple `DataGridHyperlinkColumn`, with a `Hyperlink.click` handler set up.

GamesGrid.xaml:

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SteamWishlist"
             x:Name="gamesGridControl" x:Class="MyProgram.GamesGrid"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Single" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Binding="{Binding Url}" ContentBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name">
                    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Binding="{Binding InstallLink}" Header="Install">
                    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

GamesGrid.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class GamesGrid : UserControl
{
    ...
    private void DG_Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)e.OriginalSource;
        Process.Start(link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

A few weeks ago this exact code worked just fine, but today the event is suddenly not being fired - if I set a breakpoint in `DH_Hyperlink_Click`, it's never reached.

I'm not sure where to even start debugging this issue.  Has anyone else encountered this before?

Comment: Shouldn't DataGridHyperlinkColumn do as default, what you recreated with DG_Hyperlink_Click?

Comment: @jHilscher: No, it does not.  See for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755455/handle-datagridhyperlinkcolumn-click-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the problem turned out to be yet another completely random WPF bug, sigh.

Apparently if you set `DataGrid.ItemSource` after an `await` inside a `TextBox.LostKeyboardFocus` callback, it breaks the `DataGridHyperlinkColumn.Hyperlink.Click` event.  Why?  I have no idea.

I tried everything I could think of to work around the issue, but nothing worked.  In the end I had to stop using `await` inside the callback and handle asynchronous events manually.  Sigh.